# Spring JdbcTemplate Select Single column with multiple rows

Tags: java, spring, jdbc

I am using Spring JdbcTemplate and  I couldn't find a proper way to  execute select query which returns multiple rows.  The select query has only one column. I can use `**queryForList**` but it returns a list of map which I feel is bit unnecessary just for a single column.

Query :   `select employeeName from employees;`

Any better ways or a straight forward way to    have a result of  `List<String>`  using jdbcTemplate form the above query?

Answer (score 1):

There is this overloaded method [queryForList](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#queryForList-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-) which you can use.

```
public <T> List<T> queryForList(String sql,
                                Class<T> elementType)
                         throws DataAccessException
```

Comment: this should do ?    List<String>  empList =  queryForList(sql , String.class) ;

Comment: @Stunner yes, that should do. Is it not working for you ?